# template matching algorithms and their weaknesses

Tags: image, image-processing, pattern-matching, template-matching

I am looking for a good simple (not very mathematical) introduction to pattern matching algorithms in image processing, their differences and usage.
I am also looking for the weaknesses of matching algorithms. Dissimilar things that matching algorithms mistakenly match; and similar things that they don't match (mistakenly). 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Introduction to object recognition - Selected algorithms for a wide variety of applications,
by: Marco Treiber
2010

This is a very good, current book in this field.